# mxGraph Custom Swing canvas based on user objects

Tags: java, swing, mxgraph

I would like to be able to build a custom Swing canvas based on properties of the 'value' object referenced by an mxCell ( e.g. be able to draw n Jbuttons inside a cell where n is a number stored in the value object ). Furthermore Anyone knows if it is possible to handle the events of a custom Swing Canvas?

I have insert a custom object inside a mxCell's value by redefining in my custom mxGraph :

`public void drawState(mxICanvas canvas, mxCellState state,boolean drawLabel)`

`public String convertValueToString(Object cell)`

I also had to redefine the mxGraphComponent by :

```
graphComponent = new mxGraphComponent(graph)
        {
            public mxInteractiveCanvas createCanvas()
            {
                return new myCanvas(this);
            }
        };
```

and inside `myCanvas extends mxInteractiveCanvas`  I have redefined

```
public void drawVertex(mxCellState state, String label)
        {
            Object value = ((mxCell) state.getCell()).getValue();
            Pattern p = (Pattern)value;

            for (int i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
                rendererPane.paintComponent(g, new JButton("hi"), graphComponent,
                    (int) (state.getX() + translate.getX()+i*state.getWidth()/p.length),
                    (int) (state.getY() + translate.getY()),
                    (int) state.getWidth()/p.length, (int) state.getHeight(), true);
            }
        }
```

the problem is that we have a nullpointerException on `Object value = ((mxCell) state.getCell()).getValue();`

Comment: Post [mre] please

Answer (score 0):

Ok the problem was that I tried to access parameters on a null pointer in the mxCell Edge value which was initialized with null